# Using Windows, can I tell a single program to use a specific gateway IP?

Tags: routing

My Windows PC is on two different networks, but I have programs that work better on a particular network. So for example, Outlook needs to use network A, but Chrome needs to use network B. I don't really want to have to add static routes every time I visit a new site, and there are some applications that still need to use the internet on network A.

What I think what I need is a program that can bind a program to a network. So that individual programs can use specific gateways... Is there such a program?

Even better, it would be great to have a local HTTP proxy which uses different gateways depending on the website I visit, but that might be out of the question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ForceBindIP](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) allows you to bind a program to a specific interface. You could bind it to network adapter A or network adapter B, and add it to your command line so you do not need to worry about it. I hope that helps.

Comment: Works! However it needs some improvement (you can't pass arguments to programs that you launch).

Answer (score 2):

Wingate has the ability to bind to gateway. Its free license. As long as your application can set proxy, wingate will help you to achieve this.

For applcations that cannot set proxy, ypu can use routing metric/windows nic binding to route to your required nic , then the rest , configure them to point to your wingate proxy